# QRCode reader from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I have to read (and create) QRCode using a web app (HTML, JS, PHP and MariaDB). 
My idea was to read the QRCode using JavaScript, save the data in a input tag (display: none) and send to php using the form. 
Something like this:

```
<form action="flag.php" method="post">
<button onclick="readQR()" />
<input style="display:none" id="value" name="value" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

I founded the API for creating the QRCode but not for reading. 
I was looking for some free open source API online, but none allow me to use camera. 
Can someone tell me a good API? 
Thanks you for helping me, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Don't look for an API, look for a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zxing` package. You can scan both 1D and 2D codes with it.

Pacakge: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/library